# On a Samsung Syncmaster display why does "auto adjustment" and "screen" in the menu are disabled

Tags: display

On my Samsung Syncmaster 2330, the following menu options are disabled:

- picture -> auto adjustment
- picture -> screen

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those options are generally applicable for analog (VGA, possibly DVI-A) connections only, and disabled in digital (DVI-D/HDMI) modes. You can use your video card control panel (NVidia/ATI/Intel Graphics) to perform picture adjustments.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to stretch the image I receive on 1080p because it  is smaller then the monitor size. I cant do it when using hdmi cable. I dont see where this option is.

Comment: What video card or motherboard do you have? You should be able to set these options in your video card control panel. There's an option usually called "GPU scaling" which you should disable (use native). If scaling is disabled AND the resolution is set to 1920x1080, the image should appear properly.

Comment: Thanks. it was disabled. but next to it there was a tab - scaling options which solved it.